# Error Handling mongoose with forEach loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb with express and I'm getting `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated` error when doing the following.

```
exports.deleteBooking = (req, res, next) => {
  req.body.courts.forEach(element => {
    Booking.deleteOne({$and: [
      { cid: element.cid },
      { year: element.day.year }
    ]})
    .then(result => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: result
      });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: 'error'
      })
    });
  })
};
```

I am sending an array of objects to my server and want to perform one deletion per object.

Because of the `forEach` it might run the .catch after the headers are sent to the client. What is the correct way of handling `.then` and `.catch` with a forEach loop?

Thank you!

EDIT: I forgot to add that if I would delete the `.then` and `.catch` the query would still run, and without errors. But I would like to keep the error handling in this case.

Comment: Should the response, whether it is **error** or **message** be send after the entire **forEach** loop is done or for each item in the loop?

Comment: So I tried this but then it gives the error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Promise.all instead of using forEach

```
exports.deleteBooking = (req, res, next) => {
  const promises = req.body.courts.map(element => 
    Booking.deleteOne({$and: [
      { cid: element.cid },
      { year: element.day.year }
    ]})
  );

  Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    // Handle the result response
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle the error response
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

`res.status(201).json` is within the `forEach` loop hence why you are getting the above error: you can only send data once.

To fix this, you basically need to send the `deleteOne` operations once and use **[`bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)** as it allows you to send multiple deleteOne operations to the MongoDB server in one command. It takes in input in form of an array of objects like the following

```
Booking.bulkWrite([
    { deleteOne: { filter: { cid: 1, year: 2007 } } },
    { deleteOne: { filter: { cid: 2, year: 2007 } } },
    { deleteOne: { filter: { cid: 3, year: 2007 } } },
    { deleteOne: { filter: { cid: 4, year: 2007 } } }, 
])
```

So in your case you can map `req.body.courts` array to the above `deleteOne` operations as

```
exports.deleteBooking = (req, res, next) => {
    Booking.bulkWrite(
        req.body.courts.map(({ cid, day }) => ({
            deleteOne: { filter: { cid, year: day.year } }
        }))
    ).then(message => {
        res.status(201).json({ message })
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({ error })
    })
}
```